# NXlog Input Filter

Tags: nagios, nxlog

I wanna drop a certain dnslog line from forwarding to my SIEM server..

the logline i wish to drop is the one with "sophosxl" query..  I try the the nxlog config below but its not working..

Pls help... Thanks

**My Sample  Logs File:**

```
3/2/2018 6:47:04 PM 0D84 PACKET  000000C1FF664DD0 UDP Rcv 10.5.102.203    4140   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (4)win8(4)ipv6(9)microsoft(3)com(0)

3/2/2018 6:47:04 PM 0D84 PACKET  000000C1FF703080 UDP Rcv 192.164.47.70   1035   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)go(9)microsoft(3)com(0)

3/2/2018 6:47:04 PM 0D84 PACKET  000000C1FF7070A0 UDP Rcv 10.51.51.56     a55d   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (1)4(8)sophosxl(3)net(0)

3/2/2018 6:47:04 PM 0D84 PACKET  000000C1FF705090 UDP Rcv 192.164.33.37   a4c1   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (12)filedownload(6)lenovo(3)com(0)
```

**NXLOG_CONFIG**

```html
<Input dns>
    Module  im_file
    File  "C:\dns.log"
 
    SavePos TRUE
 #InputType multilineEmtpyLine
    ReadFromLast TRUE
 Exec if ($raw_event == '') drop();
 Exec if ($message =~ /sophosxl/) drop();
    PollInterval 1
    Exec $Message = $raw_event;
 # $SyslogFacilityValue = 22;
</Input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`im_file` reads the data into the `$raw_event` field so you'll need to use that:

```
Exec if ($raw_event =~ /sophosxl/) drop();
```